# Google Compute Engine IIS Webfarm

Tags: windows, iis, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to setup a Win2008R2 IIS webfarm on Google Compute Engine.

I've got the machine setup, however when I try to add it to a network load balancer pool, the balancer consistently reports the machine as unhealthy - even if i disable healt checks. I have a single forward rule setup for port 80.

I've tried different size instances in different regions/zones to no avail.  Traffic into the load balancer never makes it to my instance, and the instance is always report as unhealthy.

For the firewall I went ahead and added a blanket rule so 0.0.0.0/0 can access all local net services (ICMP;TCP:1-65535; UDP:1-65535) and I've disabled windows firewall.

Anyone have any experience getting this working?

Answer (score 1):

Spoke with google support. "Known issue with windows instances - check back in 6 months." In the mean time, use linux or setup your own NLB within your project.

Answer (score 0):

Strange that it is not working for you. I replicated your situation and I am getting to the machine with no issues. The load balancer is forwarding traffic as expected and it reaches the system who is marked as healthy in the Lb pool.

You may want to add the following rule to the windows firewall with advanced security(make sure you use the "advanced security" one and not the default):

```
Inbound rule > New port > port 80
```

Once this is done, from your machine you can curl or telnet to the address while running a netstat on the Windows system and you should see the LB forwarding rule IP making requests :

```
$ curl IP   (locally)

$ netstat    (on the windows machine)
```

Hope this helps !